# Azure python SDK - list Service Principal permissions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am new to azure,
I am trying to write a python script that lists (in json format) the "attached policies" (see what operations on which resource are allowed both deligated and application permissions) of a **Service Principal** (I have its ID)

I looked in the documentation for `AuthorizationManagementClient` and tried

```
auth_management_client = AuthorizationManagementClient(
            credentials=credentials, subscription_id=subscription_id
        )
role_assignments_objects=auth_management_client.role_assignments.list()
for role_assignment in role_assignments_objects:
    print(role_assignment.description)
```

but I am getting  `'RoleAssignment' object has no attribute 'description'`
and I can't figure out how to use this **[role assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-authorization/azure.mgmt.authorization.v2020_04_01_preview.operations.roleassignmentsoperations?view=azure-python)** object

Using the properties of **id, name, type** don't help me because I need the actual permissions

Would appreciate some guidance here,
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to list all permissions(both delegated permission and application permission) using python?

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: If you want to know what operations you actually can and can't do, it seems better to ask for `permissions` rather than `role_assignments`, but I'm not sure how to most easily process those either (you get a list of globs).

Answer (score 0):

The `AuthorizationManagementClient` is used to manage Azure RBAC role assignments. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview). If you want to know which role assigned to the principal and the role's permissions, please refer to the following code

```
auth_management_client = AuthorizationManagementClient(
            credentials=credentials, subscription_id=subscription_id
        )
role_assignments_objects=auth_management_client.role_assignments.list()
for role_assignment in role_assignments_objects:
    print(f'the principal type : {role_assignment.principal_type}')
    print(f'The  principal Object ID : {role_assignment.principal_id}')
    result = auth_management_client.role_definitions.get_by_id(role_assignment.role_definition_id, raw=True)
    role = result.response.json()
    print('the role assigned to principal : {}'.format(role['properties']['roleName']))
    print('the role permissions : {}'.format(role['properties']['permissions']))
    break
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this answer doesn't seem to work anymore which means the SDK was probably changed since. I can find the `principal_id` property in a new `role_assignment.properties` property but I can't find `principal_type` at all for example.